# How to Create Bulk Product Attributes in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.4.5p1, bulk

I want to add more than 50 Product Attributes in the bulk. Please let me know the best way to do it in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using below script and create bulk product attributes:-

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$eavSetupFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');
$moduleSetupFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface');
$eavSetup = $eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $moduleSetupFactory]);

$attributes = [
        [
            'attribute_code' => 'new_attribute_1',
            'frontend_input' => 'text',
            'frontend_label' => 'New Attribute 1',
            'backend_type' => 'varchar',
            'is_required' => 0,
            'is_user_defined' => 1,
            'is_global' => 0,
            'is_searchable' => 1,
            'is_filterable' => 1,
            'is_comparable' => 1,
            'is_visible_on_front' => 1,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
            'used_in_product_listing' => 1,
            'used_for_sort_by' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'attribute_code' => 'new_attribute_2',
            'frontend_input' => 'text',
            'frontend_label' => 'New Attribute 2',
            'backend_type' => 'varchar',
            'is_required' => 0,
            'is_user_defined' => 1,
            'is_global' => 0,
            'is_searchable' => 1,
            'is_filterable' => 1,
            'is_comparable' => 1,
            'is_visible_on_front' => 1,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
            'used_in_product_listing' => 1,
            'used_for_sort_by' => 1,
        ],
        // add more attributes as needed
    ];

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        $attribute['attribute_code'],
        [
            'type' => $attribute['backend_type'],
            'label' => $attribute['frontend_label'],
            'input' => $attribute['frontend_input'],
            'required' => $attribute['is_required'],
            'global' => $attribute['is_global'],
            'user_defined' => $attribute['is_user_defined'],
            'searchable' => $attribute['is_searchable'],
            'filterable' => $attribute['is_filterable'],
            'comparable' => $attribute['is_comparable'],
            'visible_on_front' => $attribute['is_visible_on_front'],
            'html_allowed_on_front' => $attribute['is_html_allowed_on_front'],
            'used_in_product_listing' => $attribute['used_in_product_listing'],
            'used_for_sort_by' => $attribute['used_for_sort_by'],
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => '',
        ]
    );
}
```

I  tried and it's working fine.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**